# VCVS ideal vs exact error percentage calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier

This may be trivial but I couldn't figure how the author came up with the shown expression for the error. I believe we want to compare \$\dfrac{1}{B}\$ and \$\dfrac{A_{VOL}}{1+A_{VOL}B}\$. Doing the math I'm getting a different expression:
\$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{B}-\dfrac{A}{1+AB}}{\dfrac{A}{1+AB}} = \dfrac{1}{AB}\$
 Any help?

[image]

Comment: Your math does check out. Have you checked the book for errata?

Comment: Ahh I just figured the author is taking \$\dfrac{1}{B}\$ as reference instead of \$\dfrac{A}{1+AB}\$. Could the author actually be correct here? Somehow I feel we should take the "exact" expression as reference, not the estimation...

Comment: Again makes sense. I'd also agree that it's more natural to use \$\frac{\frac{1}{B} - \frac{A}{1 + AB}}{\frac{A}{1 + AB}}\$. Anyway, for an op amp, the extra 1 doesn't really make that much difference unless it's a precision circuit and the circuit gain is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated the difference between ideal and exact values *as a percentage of the exact value.*

The author calculated the difference between ideal and exact values *as a percentage of the ideal value.*

Replace your denominator with \$1/B\$ (and multiply by 100 to get the answer in %), and you will arrive at the same answer he did.

The author's approach is somewhat more accepted in science, as we like to see how the error compares to our expected value. For example, the commonly-used \$\chi^2\$ statistical test is defined as:

(observed - expected)^2 / expected

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test

Comment: To my mind, the "expected" value is the actual, exact value you would expect, while the "observed" value is that corrupted by noise/errors in general.

Answer (score 1):

The desirable closed loop gain is \$\frac{1}{B}\$. \$\frac{A}{1+AB}\$ is the actual closed loop gain you obtain due to finite open loop gain. Hence, the error due to finite \$A\$ should be estimated with reference to the ideal gain of \$\frac{1}{B}\$.